# User from database is not found but code do not respond with error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a simple login webpage which send a JSON request with nickname and server has to check if nickname is in connected local database in MySQL but even if is no such row with the nickname "John", code respond is Logged. What am I doing wrong?

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const mysql = require('mysql2')

const app = express()

const pool = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  port:'3306',
  user: 'root',
  password:'1234567890',
  database:'mydb'
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.static('client'))

app.post('/', (req,res) =>{
  const loginCode = `select * from users where nickname="${req.body.nickname}"`
  pool.query(loginCode, (err,resoult) =>{
    if(err){
      return console.log('NotLogged')
    }
     console.log('logged'+ resoult[0])
  })
  

})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('server is running at port 3000')
})
```

I need some help with coed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why are you expecting an error here. If there is no rows in a table that satisfy "WHERE" condition in your "SELECT" request, it just returns zero results. So I would recommend to modify **if** statement after the request in following way:

```
if (err || !resoult.length) {
  return console.log('NotLogged')
}
```